# Ensuring XMODEM Transfers a File Faithfully

Tags: linux, xmodem

I'm using XMODEM to transfer a binary file from an Ubuntu VM to an embedded Linux target, like so:

```
$ sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
$ rx test
```

<kbd>CTRL-A</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>

```
$ exec !! sx -b test
```

Now, "test" transfers successfully, but when I inspect it on both the VM and the target, I get the following:

- VM: Size = 22938 bytes
- Target: Size = 23040 bytes

In addition, the permissions are reduced on the target.

Why is this, and how can I ensure the file transferred is the same as the source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XMODEM transfers in 128-byte blocks, so the file will always be padded up to the next 128-byte boundary. YMODEM and ZMODEM include the filesize in the protocol and can transfer the correct number of bytes, but if you are limited to XMODEM, I suggest using `tar` to wrap up the file on the host, which will encode the file size and perms, then untar it on the target. `tar` might complain about the spare padding bytes, but it should still work.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. Now I just have to work out how to enable decompressing tars in my Busybox configuration!

Comment: If your busybox config has `tar` but no support for gzip or bzip, you don't need them. Just use `tar -cvf files.tar binaryfile` on the VM side, and `tar -xvf files.tar` on the target. As a bonus, you can pack as many files in there as you want. But you might want to enable compression (`-z` or `-j` options) if the files are large.